# cannot set flask environment variable in macos

Tags: python, flask

After typing

```
export FLASK_APP=use_flask.py
```

And then typing

```
printenv
```

which outputs inter alia:

```
TERM_SESSION_ID=AA805368-CF19-4631-AABB-A0112AD535CE
FLASK_APP=/users/me/documents/pcode/color/use_flask.py
USER=me
CONDA_EXE=/Users/me/Applications/miniconda3/bin/conda
```

I then place in the file `use_flask.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'hey man'
```

And then type

```
ls
```

which outputs inter alia

```
use_flask.py
```

I then type:

```
flask run
```

I get the error

```
-bash: flask: command not found
```

I have also tried exporting the full path of the use_flask.py file but that did not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran

pip install flask flask-alchemy

I thought I already had flask installed because when I typed

from flask import Flask

into my Pycharm editor and then ran the code no error message occurred.  So although I solved the problem I don't understand why it didn't work the first time.